# Не видит textView в новой активити

Tags: android-fragment, listview, android-intent, android-textview, android-switch

При переходе с фрагмента на новую активити не видит текст, картинки отображаются, подскажите где закрылся косяк.

фрагмент

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView list;
    private String[] array;
    private int category_index;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.honor
                , null);

        list = v.findViewById(R.id.listtime);
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Honors);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);




        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }
}
```

вторая активити

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView text_content;
    private ImageView iContent;

    private int position = 0;
    private int category= 0;
    private final int [] array_test = {R.string.out1, R.string.out2, R.string.out3, R.string.out4, R.string.out5};
    private final int [] array_image = {R.drawable.blackhorse};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
        text_content = findViewById(R.id.textView20);
        iContent = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        reciveIntent();
    }

    private void reciveIntent() {

        Intent i = getIntent();
        {
            assert i != null;
            category = i.getIntExtra("category", 0 );
           position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0 );
        }

switch (category){
    case 0:
        iContent.setImageResource(array_image[position]);
        text_content.setText(array_test[position]);
        break;
    case 1:

        break;
    case 2:

        break;
    case 3:

        break;
    case 4:

        break;
}
    }


}
```

разметка второй активити

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/secondactivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_width="406dp"
    android:layout_height="343dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="141dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="340dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView20"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blackhorse" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали намерение(интент), но не передаете данные из первой активности во вторую активность через него, я думаю в этом проблема. Просто так вторая активность не знает, какой элемент списка был выбран в первой.

Для передачи данных есть метод putExtra(), который есть у класса Intent. Он принимает на входе пары ключ-значение, где ключ - это имя любой вашей переменной.

Пишу в блокноте, без проверки. Там где у вас Item click:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position); //  позиция вашего списка
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

а во второй активности забираете эту переменную примерно так:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
```

Ну и теперь распоряжаетесь вашей переменной во второй активности

Comment: Сделал как вы описали, все равно выводится без текста

Comment: А значение переменной position ушло во вторую активность?

Comment: Если не ушло, то будет дефолтный 0, он описан тут int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

Comment: во второй активити defaultValue 0

Comment: Нашлась ошибка, ошибка в разметке textview

Comment: Допиши исправленный и дополненный код. Он может многим помочь

Comment: Исправил на готовый вариант